# Oracle Database XE - Own computer / local directory

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, path, dump

I work with Oracle SQL Developper on a remote host Oracle server and I would like to use (import or export) files (SQL/dump/csv files etc...) on my local computer I'm using. How could I do it without uploading those files on the server please ? If I change the default path for it, what do I have to write (like "//mycomp//C:/..." or "C:/..." ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you clarify what the locally installed Oracle XE has to do with the question? Also, are you able to create database links from XE to the remote database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have installed XE onto your own computer, one of the utilities it offers is the original export (and import), i.e. EXP and IMP. I presume that these might be useful for what you need.

Here's why: if you use Export Data Pump (a modern version of the old EXP), it creates the .DMP file on the database server - that's the *remote* computer from your point of view, so I guess you don't have access to it. EXP, on the other hand, creates the .DMP file locally, on your own computer.

Regarding the fact that you can connect to the "remote" database, you know the credentials (username, password, database name) so there should be no problem in performing both export and import, as you'd do everything locally.

EXP and IMP are command-prompt utilities, so you'd first have to start that program. It doesn't really matter which directory you're in (on Windows, that's probably C:\users\olscream or something like that). Then run:

```
exp scott/tiger@remote_db file=scott.dmp log=exp.log
```

Once it is done, create the same user in your XE database (you'd do that as a privileged user, such as SYS) and then perform import:

```
SQL> create user lf identified by lf
  2  default tablespace users
  3  quota unlimited on users
  4  temporary tablespace temp;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table, create view, create sequence, create procedure to lf;

Grant succeeded.
```

---

```
imp lf/lf@xe file=scott.dmp log=imp.log full=y
```

If something fails, have a look at the log file(s).